# How to get a specific information from the header of a netcdf file using python?

Tags: python

I have several necdf files and I need to read the value of  `"aod550:scale_factor"` and `"aod550:add_offset"` because they are different for different files. They are located in the header of my netcdf files and are additional information of `"short aod550"` (the variable which I'm interested). The part of the netcdf header looks like this:

variables:

```
short aod550(time, latitude, longitude) ;
    aod550:scale_factor = 1.44701502281421e-05 ;
    aod550:add_offset = 0.474128942375304 ;
    aod550:_FillValue = -32767s ;
```

Is there any command to read this information in python? I'm thinking in something similar to read variables. I can read the values of variable `aod550` using `aod = 'my_netcdf_file'.variables['aod550']` but it doesn't work with  `'aod550:scale_factor'` or  `'aod550:add_offset'` because they aren't variables.

Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: Are you trying to read in a global attribute from the file?  The docs have an example of doing that: http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section5

Answer (score 0):

Thank you N1B4 for your suggestion, however I'm using Scientific.IO.NetCDF.  Finally I solved my problem:

Read variable "aod":

aod = 'my_netcdf_file'.variables['aod550']

#### Read "scale_factor" and "add_offset" values:

scale_factor = aod.scale_factor[0]
add_offset = aod.add_offset[0]